# b-form-input to show/hide password with v-bind:type

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I use bootstrap.vue components. In my case "b-form-input". I want to hide and show the password by pressing the button appended to the input field. With a normal input-field it's working but with "b-fom-input" I can't get it to run. It did not work with "v-bind:type= ...". How can I solve it?

[image]

[image]

my code:

```html
<b-input-group>
  <input v-bind:type="[showPassword ? 'text' : 'password']">
  <b-input-group-append>
    <b-button @click="showPassword = !showPassword" size="sm" variant="outline-success">show</b-button>
  </b-input-group-append>
</b-input-group>
```

Update: This is the new code now: (function quick and dirty)

```js
showPassword(){
  if (this.inputtype === "text") {
    this.inputtype = "password"
  }
  if (this.inputtype === "password") {
    this.inputtype = "text"
  }
  console.log("in show PW ... ")
},
```

HTML:

```html
<b-input-group>
  <b-form-input :type="inputtype"
    :id="`type-${inputtype}`">
  </b-form-input>
  <b-input-group-append>
    <b-button @click="showPassword()"
      size="sm"
      variant="outline-success"
     >
        show
     </b-button>
    </b-input-group-append>
</b-input-group>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try to this

```html
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
        showPassword: false
     }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    Nice input <input :type="showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'">
    <button @click="showPassword = !showPassword">
      toggle it
    </button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Here is a [working demo](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNpdkFtuwyAQRbcy5cet1Jh/5PSxgaoL4IfYY4fUBsQMcaooey9+xIoqIZgLzJ2rcxWfIZTnhEKJiupoA79ph5fgI0ODrUk9w1U7gMaweX5ZaoCInKK7K8109OO3IRp9bBS0pifUTjPAbfqRt7wquQ3IgnEIvWHMCqBq7HkuNH/ZGsG6kBiq5VD8G3CvxeMMeIeC8cIFKCjCelloMZtkv0Ni9g4+6t7WP/979/D0qLcuAPZd1+fxvNrIxWfJKJeQldyii1dhhwnVbjChPJF3GePMRK8PpIXaKInMedJaHJkDKSmprSf4Jyp97GSuypgc2wFLpGF3iH4kjNlYiztGcfsDDleUeA==)

---

UPDATE: here is `bootstrap-vue` setup with Nuxt2, fully functional: https://github.com/kissu/so-input-bootstrap/blob/main/pages/index.vue#L13

Comment: the v-bind-statement is working in a normal input-field, but not in <b-form-input>

Comment: Looking [at this](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-input#input-type), it should work well. What is not working exactly? Please check your Vue devtools to narrow down the issue. @RalfBordé

Comment: when i use " <b-form-input v-bind:type="[showPassword ? 'text' : 'password']"></b-form-input>" then following error: "vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4573 [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "type". Expected String, got Array "

Comment: @RalfBordé please do not put code snippets into comments but rather edit your question. As for the warning you do have, it's as the error says: you're receiving an array in your `type` prop, while you're saying that it should be a string. Again, I recommend my answer where there is no array (because it should't be). You want to have `type="text"` at the end for example. Not `type="['text']"`, that one doesn't mean anything really.

Comment: THX. It's working now, according to your instruction. But toggling the type in a function is not working. It seems not to be reactive.

Comment: @RalfBordé please update your code with the place where you do have `showPassword` so that we can get the whole context.

Comment: code was updated

Comment: @RalfBordé I gave a repro + updated my answer.

Comment: THX, yes your example works, but without "b-form-input". This was my problem. The "normal" input field is not well formed in terms of bootstrap.

Comment: @RalfBordé as told in my 2nd comment, I don't see why it could not work. It's still using the same prop. I just tried and it's working in the same exact same way. Check my updated answer.